# How to have a numeric text box for editing a cell in a Kendo UI grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, cell, kendo-grid, editing

Looking at the Kendo UI grid demos (ASP.NET MVC CSHTML flavor), when editing a cell that is bound to an numeric value, the input becomes a `numerictextbox`, but I can't seem to reproduce that behavior (on my side in stays a plain `input`). There must be something that assigns it the `data-role` attribute or something, but what is it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use the model binding and have Kendo automatically assign the respective control, you need to setup a MVC editor template (http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/) , i.e. Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.  e.g. to render a Kendo NumericTextBox, create an editor template along these lines:

```
@model int
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox())
```

Comment: You're right, I've come to learn that since asking the question 2 months ago but didn't remember I had posted the question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define the field type as numeric in the schema.

Example: Check `UnitPrice` or `UnitsInStock`

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
        ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using the ASP.NET MVC wrappers, so I thought the type would be inferred automatically from the C# class definition (it's an `int`).

Comment: It should! Try opening the URL of your DataSource in a browser and check that what it retrieves is actually an `int`.

Comment: Indeed from the JSON it's an `int` that I receive. Using Firebug, when comparing with Kendo's demo, I seem to miss the `span` under the `td`that has the `k-numerictextbox`class.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo provides some templates under shared/EditorTemplates => here is Integer.cshtml template is ther. we can use that to show numeric value in a column. We need to set the EditorTemplateName property on column of the Grid.

EditorTemplateName("Integer") on column.Bound for that column.